# How to determine the card pool used by Pool of Vigorous Growth?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-arena

Short Version:

Is there a list of all creatures in Arena?

Long Version:

If you go to scryfall, and look at all the [9 mana value creatures available in historic](https://scryfall.com/search?q=type%3Acreature%20cmc%3D9%20legal%3Ahistoric&unique=cards&as=grid&order=name) you get a list of 5 cards (as of 2021-09-05).

Missing from that list are the cycle of [five bringer](https://scryfall.com/search?as=grid&order=name&q=bringer%20of%20type%3Acreature%20cmc%3D9) creatures.

However, if you experiment with [Pool of Vigorous Growth](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pool%20of%20Vigorous%20Growth) you'll see that it will generate tokens from the bringer cycle.

This leads me to conclude that the pool of creatures that Pool of Vigorous Growth pulls from is all creatures in Arena.  Which is different from all creatures in historic.  (Wizards often has put the bringer cycle into special events on Arena.)  Is there a list of all creatures in Arena?

One scenario where this matters:  I have a pool on the battlefield, and my opponent is in beatdown mode with a flyer with the ground fully stalemated.  I need to get a flyer and have 1 basic land in my hand.  How much mana should I pump into the pool to maximize my probability of getting a flyer?

Comment: Note: Bringers are missing on Scryfall because [it only indexes cards you can own in your collection](https://scryfall.com/docs/faqs/what-kind-of-cards-does-scryfall-index-16) and doesn't record ephemeral game pieces.

Comment: @doppelgreener: How are the Bringers "ephemeral game pieces"?  Note that they show up in a search on Scryfall for "bringer".  It seems the only reason they're not listed in the "9 CMC creatures in historic" search is that they're not legal in historic (according to Scryfall, at least).

Comment: @jwodder Because _on Arena_ they are ephemeral game pieces (tokens) only, there is no way you can ever have one of them in your collection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arena itself downloads the full set of cards supported in Arena; on a Windows machine, this can be found at `%PROGRAMFILES%\Wizards of the Coast\MTGA\MTGA_Data\Downloads\Data\` (i.e. `C:\Program Files\Wizards of the Coast\MTGA\MTGA_Data\Downloads\Data\` in the vast majority of cases); I'm sure a similar location exists for the macOS version as well.

In that directory, the primary file you'll want is `data_cards_<string of hex digits>.mtga`, although you'll need to reference the other `data_*.mtga` files as well. From there you can extract every card, token and a few other oddities that can appear on the battlefield (e.g. the Momir Vig emblem) and can then filter that to the list of creatures. The disclaimer here is that there's no guarantee that Arena actually selects from *every* creature in there when selecting a random creature, and I'm not aware of any actual specification from WotC saying how the random creature is selected. While it's obviously not a creature, there are definitely some cards in Arena's database you might not expect - for example, Mox Jet and Mox Sapphire, which were very briefly playable as part of the preconstructed Elspeth vs Ashiok event done at the launch of Theros Beyond Death.

If you're a Python programmer, [python-mtga](https://github.com/pak21/python-mtga) will do a lot of the heavy lifting for you in terms of parsing the Arena data. Here are all the 9 mana value creatures in Arena's database as of 2021-09-05:

- [Arboretum Elemental](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Arboretum%20Elemental) (GRN)
- [Blazing Archon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Blazing%20Archon) (RAV)
- [Bringer of the Black Dawn](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bringer%20of%20the%20Black%20Dawn) (5DN)
- [Bringer of the Blue Dawn](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bringer%20of%20the%20Blue%20Dawn) (5DN)
- [Bringer of the Green Dawn](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bringer%20of%20the%20Green%20Dawn) (5DN)
- [Bringer of the Red Dawn](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bringer%20of%20the%20Red%20Dawn) (5DN)
- [Bringer of the White Dawn](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bringer%20of%20the%20White%20Dawn) (5DN)
- [Chromescale Drake](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Chromescale%20Drake) (DST)
- [Colossus of Sardia](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Colossus%20of%20Sardia) (10E)
- [Demon of Death's Gate](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Demon%20of%20Death%27s%20Gate) (M11)
- [Fire Dragon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fire%20Dragon) (ME2)
- [Furnace Dragon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Furnace%20Dragon) (DST)
- [Iona, Shield of Emeria](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Iona%2C%20Shield%20of%20Emeria) (ZEN)
- [Kuro, Pitlord](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kuro%2C%20Pitlord) (CHK)
- [Molderhulk](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Molderhulk) (GRN)
- [The Tarrasque](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=The%20Tarrasque) (AFR)
- [Thing from the Deep](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Thing%20from%20the%20Deep) (ME4)
- [Titanoth Rex](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Titanoth%20Rex) (IKO)
- [Zacama, Primal Calamity](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Zacama%2C%20Primal%20Calamity) (RIX)

Full disclosure: that link is to my fork of python-mtga. My fork does have the advantage that it works on the latest Arena data though, unlike the original.

Comment: For MacOS, I suspect you need to open the application as a folder and search there. (Yes, MacOS applications are actually folders with a strict folder structure, and Finder knows where in that folder structure to look for the true executable file when you try to run it.)

Comment: [More cards](https://scryfall.com/search?q=type%3Acreature+cmc%3D9+game%3Aarena+year%3E2021&unique=cards&as=grid&order=name&dir=asc) are now available since this list was last updated.